# Accessing two sides of a user-user relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, orm, relationship

Basically, I have a users model in my rails app, and a fanship model, to facilitate the ability for users to become 'fans' of each other.

In my user model, I have:

```
has_many :fanships
has_many :fanofs, :through => :fanships
```

In my fanship model, I have:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :fanof, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "fanof_id"
```

My fanship table basically consists of :id, :user_id and :fanof_id. This all works fine, and I can see what users a specific user is a fan of like:

```
<% @user.fanofs.each do |fan| %>
    #things
<% end %>
```

My question is, how can I get a list of the users that are a fan of this specific user?

I'd like it if I could just have something like @user.fans, but if that isn't possible what is the most efficient way of going about this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://iterat.ive.ly/index.php/2010/08/31/a-user-friend-relationship-model-in-rails/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in User model:

```
has_many :my_fanclubs, :class_name => 'Fanship', :foreign_key => 'fanof_id'
has_many :fans, :through => :my_fanclubs, :source => :user, :class_name => 'User'
```

(not tested)

Comment: In the second line, I changed :source => 'user_id' to :source => :user, and it worked! thanks